# How do I get a comma separated list of ten values and not all of them?

Tags: mysql, limit, group-concat, mysql-5.7

I need to update a set of dynamic rows to a given value and I thought in the following query::

```
UPDATE tbl_names n 
SET n.queue_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_queue ORDER BY 1 DESC)
WHERE n.id IN (SELECT nm.id FROM tbl_names nm ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10)
```

But the MySQL version I am using does not allow `LIMIT` in sub queries:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

+----------------+--------+
| Variable_name  | Value  |
+----------------+--------+
| innodb_version | 5.7.27 |
| version        | 5.7.27 |
+----------------+--------+
```

Then I thought in create variables and assign the result of the sub queries to them as:

```
SET @queueId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_queue q ORDER BY 1 DESC);
SET @nameIds = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(n.id) FROM tbl_names n ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10);

UPDATE cases c SET c.queue_id=@queueId WHERE c.id IN (@nameIds);
```

But the problem is `GROUP_CONCAT` does not respect the `LIMIT` and is returning all the IDs from the table.

I know from [here](https://database.guide/how-to-return-query-results-as-a-comma-separated-list-in-mysql/) the following:

> One important thing you need to be aware of when using GROUP_CONCAT()
>   is that the result is truncated to the maximum length that is provided
>   by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value
>   of 1024.
>
> This variable’s value can be set higher, by using the following
>   syntax:
>
> SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val; Where val is an
>   unsigned integer.
>
> However, note that the effective maximum length of the return value is
>   itself constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.

But doing this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10;
SET @nameIds = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(n.id) FROM tbl_names n ORDER BY 1 DESC);
SELECT @nameIds;
```

Returns only one ID and not 10 as I would expect. What I am doing wrong? I guess I am misunderstanding how `group_concat_max_len` does work. What is the correct way to get only 10 Ids as comma separated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) with `10` as the 3d argument:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n.id), ',', 10) FROM tbl_names n
```

Comment: When I ran  `SET @nameIds = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n.id), ',', 10) FROM tbl_names n); SELECT @nameIds;` shows the results as I expect however this `UPDATE cases c SET c.queue_id=@queueId WHERE c.id IN (@nameIds);` updates nothing. Why?

Comment: `@nameIds` is a string literal. You can't use it with IN. Try: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.id, @nameIds)`.

Comment: If c.id is there in the comma separated list of @nameIds then the code should work, because this is what FIND_IN_SET() does: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Is this query right? `UPDATE cases c SET c.queue_id = @queueId WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.id, @nameIds);`

Comment: Syntactically it's correct. It will update the rows where c.id exists in @nameids.

Comment: It worked! I was using another variable name `@namesIds` instead of `@nameIds` :|

Comment: The story of every programmer's life: a simple `s` may cause hours of work. Fine if it is solved.